# How to implement an error message popup when the user exceeds a certain number of characters in Text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to implement an error message popup as shown in the screenshot
when the user exceeds a certain number of characters in the Text area using javascript/jquery.
[popup implementation required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPYcq.png)

Thank you very much in advance

Textarea code is as below

```
                   <div className="summaryInput">
                        <span className="summaryHead">Credit Risk Pricing Rationale</span>
                        <textarea value={summaryText} onChange={onsummaryChange} placeholder="Enter Text - 255 characters"></textarea>
                        <button type="button" className={`call-to-action-button ${shouldsummaryHighlight ? 'highlight' : ''}`} onClick={updatesummaryText} >Save</button>
                    </div>
```

On change where the characters are limited code

```
   const onSummaryChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value?.length > 8000)
        return false;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using JSX in your snippet, are you using React.JS ? If so, you can use the `useState` hook to hold a boolean value (that you would set inside onSummaryChange) and display conditionally your Popup component.

Comment: @CorentinPRUNE thank you for the response... yes it is .tsx file.  Popup component would be a div placed next to the textarea? can you give me more information on that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example to illustrate how to conditionally render an element base on the number of characters in your textarea: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-voice-dn8v2?file=/src/App.js

Try to type more than 5 characters, the "popup" text should show up.